# optimizing MYSQL configuration to allow faster record creation

Tags: mysql

I'm using an automated process to create posts on my WordPress website from records in a csv file using python and wp cli. The csv file has over 3 Million lines.

At the first few day posts were created at a rate of 200K posts per day and after 800K posts were created the post rate dropped to 50K and 20K per day.

To be clear. I'm not trying to load bulk data from a csv file, I'm creating individual posts using date from a csv file and WordPress API, and the creation rate of new posts has dropped drameticly.

I suspect that the problem is with the mysql config file:

```
[mysql]
port                            = 3306
socket                          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld]
# === Required Settings ===
basedir                         = /usr
bind_address                    = 127.0.0.1 # Change to 0.0.0.0 to allow remote connections
datadir                         = /var/lib/mysql
#default_authentication_plugin  = mysql_native_password # Enable in MySQL 8+ or MariaDB 10.6+ for backwards compatibility with common CMSs
max_allowed_packet              = 256M
max_connect_errors              = 1000000
pid_file                        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
port                            = 3306
skip_external_locking
skip_name_resolve
socket                          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
tmpdir                          = /tmp
user                            = mysql

default_storage_engine          = InnoDB
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 102G    # Use up to 70-80% of RAM
max_connections                 = 2000   # UPD - Important: high no. of connections = high RAM consumption
```

I have a server with 32 cores, 128GB memory and a 1TB nvme ssd

what should I add to the config file to increase the rate back to what it was in the beginning or close to it?

Comment: This happens due to the process of inserting rows requires the maintenance of all the indexes. A trick would be to remove all the indexes during the load, then add them back once the load is complete, that will take a little while but it means you build the indexes once, rather than 3 million times of maintaining them

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: I might start by hitting the MySQL Manuals [Bulk Data Loading for InnoDB Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html) Its amazing what the provide you with all for free

Comment: To be clear. I'm not trying to load bulk data from csv I'm creating individual posts with a WordPress API and the creation rate of new posts has dropped drameticly

Comment: To be clear, your question clearly states exactly the opposite: 'I'm using an automated process to create posts on my WordPress website from records in a csv file'. Please make up your mind.

Comment: I'm creating individual posts by using date from a csv file, proccesing it and posting if via WordPress API, and the creation rate of new posts has dropped drameticly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `LOAD DATA` to put that csv file into a separate table.
2. Add some indexes based on the following steps.
3. Process the data in that table using SQL queries.  Where possible write queries that act on all the rows at once *not* one row at time.
4. Then do a single (or very few) `INSERTs` to copy all those rows into the main WP tables.

One row at a time is typically 10 times as slow as doing even medium-sized batches at once.